# Calculating the local minimum of a function

Tags: functions, vector-analysis

Regarding this function $f(x,y)=1007x^2-x^{2014}+(e^y-1+2x^2)^2$.

I want to find the strict local minimum of $f$. I started calculating $\nabla$:

$\nabla (1007x^2-x^{2014}+(e^y-1+2x^2)^2)$

$=(2014x+8x(2x^2+e^y-1)-2014x^{2013},2e^y(2x^2+e^y-1))^T$

Now, the gradient must be $\nabla f(x,y)=(0,0)^T$, so I have to set the two functions like this:

**1)** $2014x+8x(2x^2+e^y-1)-2014x^{2013}=0$

**2)** $2e^y(2x^2+e^y-1)=0$

Here's where I'm stuck. How do I solve the first equation for x, since I have $x^{2013}$?

Comment: In your second equation, 2e^y can never equal zero, so your bracket expression has to be zero.  And knowing that, your first equation becomes just a function of x.

Comment: @Maciek:Thanks, I got a critical point at $(0,0)$, which is the local minimum. Is there a way to show, that it is a **strict** local minimum and whether it is also a **global** minimum or not?

Comment: In the function you specified there is no global minimum.  For $y=0$, the function values $f(x,0) = 1007x^2 - x^{2014} + 4x^4$ are unbounded below.
As to the strict minimum, $f(x,y) \geq 1007x^2 - x^{2014} = x^2(1007 - x^{2012})$ which is positive for all small, non-zero $x$.  When $x = 0$, $f(0,y) = (e^y-1)^2$ is also positive.

Comment: @Maciek Thanks again, sir.